# How to change the scroll-bar style in css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How can I change the scroll bar style in `css` or change the different UI in chrome or any browser. I have seen many sites with different user interfaces.
Can this be done with `css` or `html`?

Comment: With CSS3 you can achieve this. You might find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS) article helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOEJaK) . You can also check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/674478/Customize-Scrollbars-using-CSS).

Use css like this

```
html {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3em;
  font: 100%/1.4 serif;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.2em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
body {
    scrollbar-face-color: #000000;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #2D2C4D;
    scrollbar-highlight-color:#7D7E94;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #7D7E94;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #2D2C4D;
    scrollbar-track-color: #7D7E94;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #C1C1D1; 
}
```

One more [EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/zakkain/pen/phjBC) with hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've just learned with this topic that we can customize scrollbar in CSS3...
But it doesn't seem very efficient in every browser.

What I advise is that you choose (if you can) a jQuery plugin instead. Like http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html .
I often use it. It's very powerful, customizable and interoperable !